# mod_rewrite redirect root directory, rewrite subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a url shortening service for my organization.  I want to **rewrite** shortened urls to my index.php file, but **redirect** requests to the root to my main website, ie:

Request: short.domain.tld/abc
User sees: short.domain.tld/abc
Page served up: short.domain.tld/index.php?code=abc

Request: short.domain.tld/
User sees: website.domain.tld
Page served up: website.domain.tld (on my website server)

My .htaccess file is currently:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-s 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php?code=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://website.domain.tld/
```

I'm unsure how to differentiate between requests for subdirectories and requests for the root of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in the .htaccess file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  short\.domain\.tld  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php       [NC]
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?   /index.php?code=$1  [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  short\.domain\.tld  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/$      
RewriteRule  .*    http://website.domain.tld  [R=301,L]
```

Maps internally

`http://short.domain.tld/abc` with or without trailing slash (Displayed in address bar)

To

`http://short.domain.tld/index.php?code=abc`

Where string `abc` is assumed to be dynamic.

---

Or redirects permanently

`http://short.domain.tld/` without segment path

To:

`http://website.domain.tld/`  (Displayed in address bar)

Comment: Thanks!  I believe I had the regex wrong for the shortcodes.  I modified your rules a bit - removed the RewriteBase directive and removed the %{HTTP_HOST} directives - everything still works.  Thanks again.